# passing ExpandoObject as parameter

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have some sql functions like this (wrote in C#):

```
public void Query(string sqlText, ExpandoObject paramSet) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...)
    foreach (var item in paramSet) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(...);
    ...
}
```

And want to call like this:

```
dbHandler.Query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE loginID = @loginID", new { loginID = "username" });
```

The reason I want to use ExpandoObject to hold parameter set is:

1.ExpandoObject implements IDictionary interface so reflections can be avoid;

2.I don't want to write additional lines declaring a new Dictionary object to store values(passing annonymous type does less coding).

However the compiler reports error as follows:

```
cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string loginID>' to 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most simple answer is to not reinvent this yourself. Just use [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) it provides these kinds of extensions and deals with arguments plus mapping of the resulting reader to your classes.

Comment: thanx for that tool!

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous type is not an expando object.You need to make one.

```
dynamic user = new ExpandoObject();
user.loginID = "username";
dbHandler.Query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE loginID = @loginID", user);
```

But now you are not properly setting the SqlDbType of the parameters and that could lead to unexpected behavior in your database. You would have to call `GetType()` on the expando's fields and map to SqlDbType and there's a mess that you seem to be trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes it works however it wastes extra lines to declare some variables as "dynamic" which i'd like to avoid. Anyway thanks alot!